# Remove duplicate from KOObservable array

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Want to remove duplicate values from KoObservableArray. I have following JS file. I want to bind the name column in the UI as dropdown as well as to remove the duplicate values.

Suggest the best way to do the same.

JS File

```
$(function () {
    var initialData = [
    { name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
    { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
    { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
    { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 213, price: 25.00 },
    { name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
    { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
    { name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
    { name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
    { name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
];

    var PagedGridModel = function (items) {
        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);       
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));
});

HTML File 
<body>

<nav>
<label for="name">Name</label>
        <select id="name" data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption:'All'">
        </select>
</nav>

</body>
```

The above give me drop down with duplicate names.

Comment: One way would be to create a computed array which would pick only the unique names and then bind your select to this variable. Another way would be to not add duplicates to your main array in the first place.

Comment: only name field is duplicate, but other fields are not, so can't filter for distinct values. Can i have an example for a computed array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below for a sample of how you can have a computed observable returning an array. I have just written down the logic for filtering but it may not be correct or optimal, I will leave it to you to improve on it.

```
$(function () {
    var initialData = [
    { name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
    { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
    { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
    { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 213, price: 25.00 },
    { name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
    { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
    { name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
    { name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
    { name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
];

    var PagedGridModel = function (items) {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray(items);       
        self.uniqueItems = ko.computed({
            var filteredArray = [];
            var i;
            $.each(self.items(), function (index, item) {
                 bool alreadyAdded = false;
                 for (i in filteredArray) {
                      if (filteredArray[i].name == item.name) {
                            alreadyAdded = true;
                      }
                 }
                  if (!alreadyAdded) {
                       filteredArray.push(item);
                  }
            });
            return  filteredArray;
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel(initialData));
});
```

And finally in your HTML

```
<select id="name" data-bind="options: uniqueItems, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption:'All'">
</select>
```